# Should link disclose more information or open a popup menu?

Tags: menu, lists, deletion

I have a list of links that reference resources. Users interact with a link in two ways: 1. display a short description of the resource, and 2. delete the link from the list.

Two options are being discussed for link behavior:

1. Clicking a link slides open the description under the link. Each link has a Delete icon next to it for removing the link. Clicking the link again hides the description.
2. Clicking a link opens a popup menu with two options: Show Info and Delete. Clicking Show Info slides open the description under the link. Delete removes the link. Clicking the link again opens a menu with Hide Info and Delete.

Which link behavior is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to understand your context a bit more, but:

I'd go with 1 if: Your users are more interested in reading the description than removing the link. It's also easier than 2 as 2 requires the user to take 2 steps whatever they want to do - but again, it depends on context.

As an alternative: How about having the description as a tooltip, with an 'x' next to the link? The user can then hover or click to see the description, and click 'x' to delete (with an confirmation dialog to avoid errors).

Comment: Users would likely read descriptions much more often than deleting links.

Answer (score 0):

In general implementation should depend on context. In some case it would be more convient not to delete the items but mark some of them as appropriate (i.e. inverse task).

Saying of eliminating user load, you can minimize user clicks by displaying description and delete button on mouseover.

Or use lens effect when you display wrapped content of link (i.e. link name and first words of description) and unwrap it on mouseover. In this case user could quicker take decision even without unwrapping the link. Though in this case delete buttons should stand to the right side of the items.

Comment: I like the hover idea, but the application will run on both laptops and iPads, so we can't display information on mouseover.

Comment: Then partial display of content (wrapped) could be nice. In some case reading only the part of description could lead to link removal. Of course by tapping the link user could read the whole description. The idea is the same – to minimize user clicks/taps.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Interaction schema]

I've pictured [interaction schema for touch screen devices](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15007236/link.png). User should only press to view  description and drag to trash without any additional touches and clicking.

Comment: How interesting. I would never have thought that revealing the description and optionally deleting the list item could be accomplished with a single touch interaction.